# Maximo work order query looking for pm's with extdate populated

Tags: sql, maximo

I am trying to run a query in Maximo work order tracking to find PM work orders that are not COMP, CLOSE, COMPFLD, or CAN where the PM.EXTDATE is not NULL.  Here is what I have but it does not work.

((wosequence is null and status not in ('COMP', 'COMPFLD') and (woclass = 'WORKORDER' or woclass = 'ACTIVITY') and upper(crewid) = 'SD' and historyflag = 0 and istask = 0 and siteid = 'SD' and pmnum like '%') and (exists (select from MAXIMO_PM where ((MAXIMO_WORKORDER.PMNUM = MAXIMO_PM.PMNUM) and (MAXIMO_PM.EXTDATE Like '%')))))

Answer (score 1):

The table names are `PM` and `WORKORDER`. Leave off the `MAXIMO_` bit.

Also, you need to select something in your PM subquery. Change `select from PM` to `select 1 from PM`.

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to add a 1 after (select.  (select 1

Comment: I have incorporated your comments into my answer. I see you are new here. Welcome! If my answer helped you, you should accept it. You can also up-vote it if you think it was high quality.